# Why are all Stark Direwolves different?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

[image: THE STARK DIREWOLVES]In the Game of Thomes S1E1 we see Ned and his party of Robb, Bran, Jon, Theon and Ser Rodrick to find a dead direwolf mother and her many little cubs and they they take the cubs, one for each of the Stark children.
But we can see then and on various occasions when these pets are shown that they are all different looking.
Ghost is completly white with red eyes;
Greywind is mostly gray with slightly white underbelly;
Lady and Nymeria are both nearly white with a slight gray shade near the ears;
Summer is white with slight shades of yellow and gold;
and finally Shaggydog is nearly completly black.
So if all these cubs are born to the same mother how are they all so different.
Does this happens in Canidae family animals or am I missing something?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this a biology question about actual wolfs? If so, this is the wrong SE. If this is about the GoT TV universe, I think this scene establishes that the dire wolfs there at least can be in the presence of different looking cubs when they die.

Comment: This is a question about biology of direwolves, who are indeed a par of GoT universe and do not exist in reality.So I don't think the Biology SE will entertain questions on non existent mammals.

Comment: But you are asking about the possibility of different coloured pubs in a litter of Canidae. That is entirely a biology question. If you are asking is this possible within the GoT/ASoIaF-Universe, the answer is clearly yes, the author described them as such. If you are asking if this is possible in real life, than it is a question about real life biology and belongs at [biology.se] And I am fairly certain if you phrase the question as such, they not only would answer, but more importantly, they would have the expertise to give one. +1 for it being an intersting question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this as a question asking for a scientific explanation. There are more appropriate stacks for that.

Comment: @user94418 If I understand your comment correctly, you accept the fact that this species can have different looking pubs (you can clearly see it in the series) and are now asking if this happens in the canidae family throughout the entire GoT universe? Why this is interesting to you, well, not my business, but if that is your question, please word it so. I believe that would be "on topic". Btw I ask myself the very same question every time they have siblings on some show, I think it is established in TV land that genetics do not exist ;)

Comment: To answer you question, however, that's how genetics work in the real world too.